# How to upgrade Ubuntu on a dual boot system?

Tags: upgrade, dual-boot

I have a dual boot system with a previous 10.04 version of Ubuntu and Windows 7.

I need to upgrade the existing version of Ubuntu while working on my dual boot safely.

Is there a specific way to do that?

Comment: A distribution upgrade on one partition will not modify the other OS.  The only possible change effecting the other OS will be an upgrade from GRUB to GRUB2 (and I'm not even sure if this will happen on an upgrade vs a fresh install), however GRUB2 should still auto detect and configure a boot option for Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever it comes to upgrading Ubuntu, there are many ways to do it. What I would recommend (especially to keep the integrity of your dual boot) is to open up "Update Manager" from the Dash menu/Applications menu. Then, run the upgrade to 12.04 that is listed near the top. This will upgrade 12.04 but there will be no negative effect to your dual boot.

Comment: I did this and had no troubles. Same for the last 4 versions of Ubuntu on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade won't disturb your dual boot setup. On Ubuntu, you can initiate the release upgrade by a simple command:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

I can confirm that it works flawlessly for an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS on a dual boot system with Windows 10 (using GRUB 2 as Bootloader, without full disk encryption).