# How to migrate from ubuntu 14 to 16 without affecting dual boot windows in background

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade, 16.04

I have no useful data in the old ubuntu . I don't have a live Windows CD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrage Ubuntu on a dual boot system?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143116/how-to-upgrage-ubuntu-on-a-dual-boot-system)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using grub as your boot loader, you can use the update utility in Ubuntu 14.04 to migrate. That's all pretty straight forward, as Ubuntu 16.04 will reinstall grub 2 anyways.

Comment: hey i have an .iso copy . can't afford to download again. i am facing several issues in ubuntu 14 and have no important files in it . can u suggest how do i proceed. i installed ubuntu using efi boot stick. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 will not effect your windows boot, the windows boot option will be added to the grub menu, so you can boot into windows by just selecting that.

Until Ubuntu 16.04.1 release, you have to do in by typing in terminal `do-release-upgrade -d` and it will upgrade you to 16.04 (development distro) but the `do-release-upgrade` without `-d` switch which is the general upgrade command to upgrade from LTS to LTS, will take effect after 16.04.1 release, may be sometime in July. You can wait for that or you can do it now because after upgrading to 16.04 (developemant version), you can easily upgrade to 16.04.1 by just running in terminal:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y full-upgrade
```

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? But if you want to reinstall, use Something Else. Just be sure to boot installer in same mode as Windows is installed. But first do a full Windows backup and also make a Windows repair flash drive. If you have gpt then it is UEFI and you have partitions you do not need to create new one's just choose change. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation