# Upgrading from Kubuntu to Ubuntu via CLI

Tags: command-line, system-installation, upgrade, kubuntu

I currenltly run Kubuntu on my dell laptop
I need to change the distro from Kubuntu to kubuntu
I have tried to run distro upgrade and release upgrade but that didnt help as its the latest Kubuntu release.

Is there a way to update to ubuntu via cli from kubuntu.

Comment: The main difference between kubuntu and ubuntu is the choice of desktop.  You can install the desktop, I do not know enough to recommend without problems, or you can install ubuntu over or dual boot with kubuntu.  Do not think you can upgrade from kubuntu to ubuntu.  Installing Ubuntu over Kubuntu will have a good chance to destroy your data.  Do not know if adding Gnome desktop will play nice with Kubuntu desktop,  can try on a VM copy of your system first.

Comment: You can try this [link](https://itsfoss.com/replace-linux-from-dual-boot/) I found it quite helpful when I switched from Ubuntu to Kali.

Comment: Here is a similar question, but backwards.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196008/how-can-i-change-to-kubuntu-from-ubuntu?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You want to switch to ubuntu from the command line right?

**You must first update Kubuntu and then switch to the default desktop environment:**

- Upgrade Kubuntu:

  do-release-upgrade
- Install GNOME and gdm3:

  sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop gnome-shell gdm3

**A "Default display manager" menu should appear. Choose gdm3 as default and reboot system.**

**After the system restarts, it will be received by the GDM. Choose Ubuntu as your desktop environment.**

**If you want to remove kubuntu, you must follow these commands:**

```
sudo apt autoremove plasma* sddm

sudo apt autoremove kde* qml-module-org-kde* libkf5kdelibs4support* libkf5libkdepim* software-properties-kde xdg-desktop-portal-kde libkde* konsole
```

**After that you should have your Ubuntu system working properly.**