# Just installed KDE and libreoffice calc is the default file association for inappropriate files

Tags: kde, libreoffice, file-association, file-type

Right click on many kinds of files such as tar.bz2, ogg-vorbis etc. and the context menu always shows Libreoffice calc.  The software to handle these files is installed and appears in open with context menu.

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-28-generic
OS Type: 64-bit

Comment: Which version of Kubuntu are you using? This is not supposed to be the default behavior. What all changes have you performed? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1388837/edit) the question.

Comment: Doh! I actually installed KDE on top of Gnome which I have heard elsewhere is, um, not ideal...I should probably install Kubuntu from scratch and go from there. Thank you for your response. I guess I will update when I am finished with that.

Comment: I have the same issue on 22.04. I think I was able to get rid of it in the past, but after last LibreOffice update it is here again ...

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Kubuntu from scratch on reformatted partitions and the weird problem is gone.  Not that surprising really.  Kubuntu installer crashed and system became unbootable when I tried to do it without formatting, which I [read](https://askubuntu.com/a/1196013/1349574) should work sometimes and preserve user data/some software. I ended up creating a separate `/home` partition so this kind stuff might be a little easier in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the solution. **System Settings**, go to **File Associations**, expand **application** and click on **x-bzip-compressed-tar** and then update applications or sort them by your priorities.

In my case it opened also any plain text file like sha512, so I had to update different type, but the principle is still the same.

[image: Screenshot]